# Value of infinite sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin n}{\sqrt{n}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, dirichlet-series

The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin n }{\sqrt{n}}$ is clearly convergence as can be shown with the Dirichlet's test. But what is this value and how to evaluate this sum to get a closed form solution?

With WolframAlpha I arrive for example at:

$$\dfrac{1}{2} i (Li_{1/2}(e^{-i}) - Li_{1/2}(e^i))≈1.04398 $$

Comment: Most series don't have a closed-form, this is one of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [Clausen function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function#General_definition) of order 1/2 given by

$$\operatorname{Si}_{1/2}(1)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(n)}{\sqrt n}$$

By applying Euler's formula for $\sin(z)=\frac1{2i}(e^{iz}-e^{-iz})$ one gets the relation to the [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function#Relation_to_the_polylogarithm):

$$\operatorname{Si}_{1/2}(1)=\frac1{2i}(\operatorname{Li}_{1/2}(e^i)-\operatorname{Li}_{1/2}(e{-i}i))$$

Quicker numerical evaluation can be done using various relations such as the above. Applying a more brute force approach, one may take the [Cesaro summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation):

$$\operatorname{Si}_{1/2}(1)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^k\frac{\sin(j)}{\sqrt j}$$

[Evaluating the above](https://tio.run/##VY5BCoMwFET3OcWgm6QlMdZdwSP0BCJiaUUJ/drELEQ8exqli3b3Zpj/@Nbfl0AoURSXXAfnX5E1a61tl2bsmli42FQ1Y91oYTAQcqWIYZ@eS/BcciO10iIjgRNu7dwrNxA3Atk3ve0cI8OfVU3e9TySYE96/Oi1OvyTnx2SdCVptiuQrn/X1bGSplb7Hxl4ZLEluyqEDw) at $n=33208$ gives us

$$\operatorname{Si}_{1/2}(1)\simeq1.0439773797177627$$

Comment: Being "surprised" by your result, I made a few calculations. I think that I never saw something slower. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

Another possible form is
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin (n)}{\sqrt{n}}=\Im\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{in}}{\sqrt{n}}\right)=\Im\left(\text{Li}_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(e^{-i}\right)\right)$$ which can rewrite as
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin (n)}{\sqrt{n}}=\Im\left(\frac{(-1)^{1/4} \zeta \left(\frac{1}{2},1-\frac{1}{2 \pi }\right)+(-1)^{3/4} \zeta
   \left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2 \pi }\right)}{i\sqrt{2} }\right)$$ and its numerical value is 
$$1.04398210284916152745329487258675045979090714472261220374895285877066908586$$ which is quite close to
$$\frac{1+2\log (5)}{20 (\zeta (3)-1)}=1.043982105$$

**Edit**

What looked interesting (at least to me) was to compute the partial sum
$$S_k=\sum_{n=1}^{10^k}\frac{\sin (n)}{\sqrt{n}}$$ Using double precision, some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 &     1.2080477203 \\
 2 &     0.9400223327 \\
 3 &     1.0407653236 \\
 4 &     1.0511687406 \\
 5 &     1.0469310313 \\
 6 &     1.0429497497 \\
 7 &     1.0443111845 \\
 8 &     1.0440619434 \\
 9 &     1.0439664828 \\
\cdots   &   \cdots \\
\infty & 1.0439821028
\end{array}
\right)$$

Quite slow, isn't it ?

Comment: You don't want to compute the series at powers of tens, but rather at near multiples of $2\pi$. It converges a tad faster if you choose your bound like so.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt. I made it that way on purpose. Cheers :-)